# data organization in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am moving from RDBMS to Cassandra.
Documentation saya that Cassandra is a column family based data structure. It means that a row will be divided in multiple column families and particular column family of all the rows will be stored at one place for fast access. 
 At the same time it is written that a row belongs to only one column family in Cassandra and think of Cassandra model like `Map<RowKey, SortedMap<ColumnKey, ColumnValue>>` . So how does is that column family structure now ? As row keys are used as first level map, all the columns of a particular row will be close on disk, rather than column families of all the rows. 
 What I am getting wrong ? An example or link to some clear documents will be much appreciated as most of the blogs have copied a page from `Nosql Distilled`

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of good articles on DataStax site: [about data modeling](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling), [PK structures](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html) and [stuff](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_intro_c.html).
You can think about column families as tables in RDBMS terms but with another set of capabilities and limitations.